# Laravel auth failure - no quotes in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

scratching my head on this one...
getting a 500 error at login which seems to be tied to the inability for laravel (5.7) to run this query

```
SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = fred@example.com and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

checking it in mysql (by logging in as the laravel user - it definitely fails..
the correct query should have been

```
select * from `users` where `email` = 'fred@example.com' and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

Note the quotes around the email

Note the source of this is Laravel internal processes, not anything I've written.

I did do a composer update recently, and can only suspect something has broken, but it seems so fundamental that I'm doubtful its was a laravel update

Comment: Why are you would like to runnig sql something just like this. You can do  this with query builder laravel with all magic working!!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Comment: this is the error log text in storage/logs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amazingly this was solved by realising nginx was using an older version of php as the fpm socket... For future explorers having a WTF moment over this..

I have *no* idea why a slightly different version of php would result in such an obscure error.. but hey, its laravel and magic...

So solution steps.. check version of php running, `php -v`, check sockets `ls /run/php` (on Ubuntu, you platform might be different), check /etc/nginx/sites-available configurations.. Then make sure they are all using the same php version

Answer (score 0):

### Use the Laravel Eloquent Query Builder

Assuming your model for the users table is named "User" then try using the following query:

```
$users = User::where('email','=','fred@example.com')
               ->wherenull('deleted_at')
               ->first();
```

Laravel should then take care of all the injection prevention and putting strings in the correct format for the query.